# Prolog - increment by given number

Tags: recursion, prolog, calculation

I have a couple of linked elements with provided cost for traversing them:

```
link(a, b, 100).
link(b, c, 223).
link(c, d, 311).
```

I want to find whether the traversal is possible and if it is then return the total cost.

So that the question `?-count(a, d, X).` returns `X = 634`.

Here is my attempt at doing it:

```
sum(A, B, X) :-
    X is A + B.
count(Start, Finish, Cost) :-
    link(Start, Finish, Cost).
count(Start, Finish, Cost) :-
    link(Start, Through, Tempcost),
    count(Through, Finish, Newcost),
    sum(Cost, Tempcost, Newcost).
```

The **problem** is that while I have a general idea how to increment by a fixed number I have a hard time adding up totally different numbers and passing them on to recursion.

My current code returns an "Argument Insuff. Instantiated" error. I know that it often has something to do with the order of the code so I tried to change it around but so far had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic mistake is that you here sum up the `Cost` with `Tempcost` to a `Newcost`. But `Newcost` is here the cost to get from `Through` to `Finish`.

The relation is thus in the opposite way you define it. We can say that the `Cost` to get from `Start` to `Finish` is the same as the cost to take the `Start` to `Through` (with a `HopCost`), plus the `RestCost`: the cost to get from `Through` to `Finish`:

```
sum(A, B, X) :-
    X is A + B.

count(Start, Finish, Cost) :-
    link(Start, Finish, Cost).
count(Start, Finish, Cost) :-
    link(Start, Through, HopCost),
    count(Through, Finish, RestCost),
    sum(HopCost, RestCost, Cost).
```